# Imitate google maps js "drift" effect

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, dictionary, openmap

I just thought about moving from google maps to open street maps. Now there's a nice library to make the move more easy called [Leaflet from Cloudmade](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/). After playing around with it, I found one big "plus": Numbers for houses. Sadly one big minus too: It's missing the "drift" effect. So if you open the map on your mobile and push the map around with a fast move of your finger, it doesn't stop immediately when you stop the move, but starts slowing down. This way you can easily get over larger distances without the need to zoom or a lot of finger move.

> Q: Does anyone know of any library or similar that could do this? I'll get around the coding itself, but I a) don 't know the name of the effect and b) can't find a starting point even for searching.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the term would be "inertial scrolling" or "momentum scrolling" - don't quote me though

Answer (score 2):

I am not a JavaScript specialist, so I cannot code an example, but you can obtain the idea, needs and math from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503002/757830). It is written in Delphi, but I think it is manageable to extract what is necessary.