# How to create a slowing scroll effect on a scrollbox?

Tags: image, delphi, scroll, effect, easing

I like to create a smooth slowing scroll effect after panning an image in a scrollbox. Just like panning the map in [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com). I'm not sure what type it is, but exactly same behaviour: when dragging the map around with a fast move, it doesn't stop immediately when you release the mouse, but it starts slowing down.

Any ideas, components, links or samples?

Comment: from what I know, there's no such thing around, most likely you will have to come up with your implementation.

Comment: i found AnimateEasing class but i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### The idea:

As per your comment, it should feel like Google Maps and thus while dragging the image, the image should stick to the mouse pointer; no special effects required so far. But at releasing the mouse button, the image needs to move (the scroll box needs to pan) further in the same direction and with a gradually easing speed, starting with the dragging velocity at the moment the mouse button was released.

So we need:

- a drag handler for when the mouse is pressed: `OnMouseMove` will work,
- the panning speed at the moment the mouse is released: during the drag operation, we will track the latest speed with a timer,
- something that still moves the image after the mouse release: we use the same timer,
- a way to update the GUI: updating the image position, scrolling the scroll box and updating the scroll bar positions. Luckily, setting the position of the scroll bars of the scroll box will do all that,
- a function to gradually decrease the speed after mouse release. I chose for a simple linear factor, but you can experiment with that.

#### Setup:

- Drop a `TScrollBox` on your form, create event handlers for `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseMove` and `OnMouseUp` and set the `DoubleBuffered` property to `True` (this needs to be done runtime),
- Drop a `TTimer` on your form, set its interval to 15 milliseconds (~ 67 Hz refresh rate) and create an event handler for `OnTimer`,
- Drop a `TImage` on the scroll box, load a picture, set the size to something big (e.g. 3200 x 3200), set `Stretch` to `True` and set `Enabled` to `False` to let the mouse events through to the scroll box.

#### Code (for scroll box):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Forms, JPEG, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox: TScrollBox;
    Image: TImage;
    TrackingTimer: TTimer;
    procedure ScrollBoxMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ScrollBoxMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure ScrollBoxMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure TrackingTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDragging: Boolean;
    FPrevScrollPos: TPoint;
    FPrevTick: Cardinal;
    FSpeedX: Single;
    FSpeedY: Single;
    FStartPos: TPoint;
    function GetScrollPos: TPoint;
    procedure SetScrollPos(const Value: TPoint);
  public
    property ScrollPos: TPoint read GetScrollPos write SetScrollPos;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScrollBox.DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

function TForm1.GetScrollPos: TPoint;
begin
  with ScrollBox do
    Result := Point(HorzScrollBar.Position, VertScrollBar.Position);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBoxMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := True;
  FPrevTick := GetTickCount;
  FPrevScrollPos := ScrollPos;
  TrackingTimer.Enabled := True;
  FStartPos := Point(ScrollPos.X + X, ScrollPos.Y + Y);
  Screen.Cursor := crHandPoint;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBoxMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
    ScrollPos := Point(FStartPos.X - X, FStartPos.Y - Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBoxMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetScrollPos(const Value: TPoint);
begin
  ScrollBox.HorzScrollBar.Position := Value.X;
  ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position := Value.Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.TrackingTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Delay: Cardinal;
begin
  Delay := GetTickCount - FPrevTick;
  if FDragging then
  begin
    if Delay = 0 then
      Delay := 1;
    FSpeedX := (ScrollPos.X - FPrevScrollPos.X) / Delay;
    FSpeedY := (ScrollPos.Y - FPrevScrollPos.Y) / Delay;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (Abs(FSpeedX) < 0.005) and (Abs(FSpeedY) < 0.005) then
      TrackingTimer.Enabled := False
    else
    begin
      ScrollPos := Point(FPrevScrollPos.X + Round(Delay * FSpeedX),
        FPrevScrollPos.Y + Round(Delay * FSpeedY));
      FSpeedX := 0.83 * FSpeedX;
      FSpeedY := 0.83 * FSpeedY;
    end;
  end;
  FPrevScrollPos := ScrollPos;
  FPrevTick := GetTickCount;
end;

end.
```

#### Code (for panel):

And in case you do not want the scroll bars then use the following code. The example uses a panel as container, but that could be any windowed control or the form itself.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Forms, JPEG, ExtCtrls, Math;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Panel: TPanel;
    Image: TImage;
    TrackingTimer: TTimer;
    procedure PanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure PanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure TrackingTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDragging: Boolean;
    FPrevImagePos: TPoint;
    FPrevTick: Cardinal;
    FSpeedX: Single;
    FSpeedY: Single;
    FStartPos: TPoint;
    function GetImagePos: TPoint;
    procedure SetImagePos(Value: TPoint);
  public
    property ImagePos: TPoint read GetImagePos write SetImagePos;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel.DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

function TForm2.GetImagePos: TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := Image.Left;
  Result.Y := Image.Top;
end;

procedure TForm2.PanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := True;
  FPrevTick := GetTickCount;
  FPrevImagePos := ImagePos;
  TrackingTimer.Enabled := True;
  FStartPos := Point(X - Image.Left, Y - Image.Top);
  Screen.Cursor := crHandPoint;
end;

procedure TForm2.PanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
    ImagePos := Point(X - FStartPos.X, Y - FStartPos.Y);
end;

procedure TForm2.PanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;

procedure TForm2.SetImagePos(Value: TPoint);
begin
  Value.X := Max(Panel.ClientWidth - Image.Width, Min(0, Value.X));
  Value.Y := Max(Panel.ClientHeight - Image.Height, Min(0, Value.Y));
  Image.SetBounds(Value.X, Value.Y, Image.Width, Image.Height);
end;

procedure TForm2.TrackingTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Delay: Cardinal;
begin
  Delay := GetTickCount - FPrevTick;
  if FDragging then
  begin
    if Delay = 0 then
      Delay := 1;
    FSpeedX := (ImagePos.X - FPrevImagePos.X) / Delay;
    FSpeedY := (ImagePos.Y - FPrevImagePos.Y) / Delay;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (Abs(FSpeedX) < 0.005) and (Abs(FSpeedY) < 0.005) then
      TrackingTimer.Enabled := False
    else
    begin
      ImagePos := Point(FPrevImagePos.X + Round(Delay * FSpeedX),
        FPrevImagePos.Y + Round(Delay * FSpeedY));
      FSpeedX := 0.83 * FSpeedX;
      FSpeedY := 0.83 * FSpeedY;
    end;
  end;
  FPrevImagePos := ImagePos;
  FPrevTick := GetTickCount;
end;

end.
```

#### Code (for paint box):

And when the image's dimensions are limitless (e.g. a globe), you can use a paint box to glue the image's ends together.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, ExtCtrls, JPEG;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Painter: TPaintBox;
    Tracker: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PainterMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PainterMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure PainterMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PainterPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TrackerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDragging: Boolean;
    FGraphic: TGraphic;
    FOffset: Integer;
    FPrevOffset: Integer;
    FPrevTick: Cardinal;
    FSpeed: Single;
    FStart: Integer;
    procedure SetOffset(Value: Integer);
  public
    property Offset: Integer read FOffset write SetOffset;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  FGraphic := TJPEGImage.Create;
  FGraphic.LoadFromFile('gda_world_map_small.jpg');
  Constraints.MaxWidth := FGraphic.Width + 30;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FGraphic.Free;
end;

procedure TForm3.PainterMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := True;
  FPrevTick := GetTickCount;
  FPrevOffset := Offset;
  Tracker.Enabled := True;
  FStart := X - FOffset;
  Screen.Cursor := crHandPoint;
end;

procedure TForm3.PainterMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
    Offset := X - FStart;
end;

procedure TForm3.PainterMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;

procedure TForm3.PainterPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Painter.Canvas.Draw(FOffset, 0, FGraphic);
  Painter.Canvas.Draw(FOffset + FGraphic.Width, 0, FGraphic);
end;

procedure TForm3.SetOffset(Value: Integer);
begin
  FOffset := Value;
  if FOffset < -FGraphic.Width then
  begin
    Inc(FOffset, FGraphic.Width);
    Dec(FStart, FGraphic.Width);
  end
  else if FOffset > 0 then
  begin
    Dec(FOffset, FGraphic.Width);
    Inc(FStart, FGraphic.Width);
  end;
  Painter.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm3.TrackerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Delay: Cardinal;
begin
  Delay := GetTickCount - FPrevTick;
  if FDragging then
  begin
    if Delay = 0 then
      Delay := 1;
    FSpeed := (Offset - FPrevOffset) / Delay;
  end
  else
  begin
    if Abs(FSpeed) < 0.005 then
      Tracker.Enabled := False
    else
    begin
      Offset := FPrevOffset + Round(Delay * FSpeed);
      FSpeed := 0.83 * FSpeed;
    end;
  end;
  FPrevOffset := Offset;
  FPrevTick := GetTickCount;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Excellent work! Just one note, if you drag the image too slow (without drop) it's shaking (however if you drop it, it works fine).

Comment: @TLama No problem here. I'm inclined to attribute that to a too large image (or a too slow computer ;)). Did you try without double buffering?

Comment: @NGLN, I've tried large and middle size images. About performance, I can keep double buffering off and it doesn't even flicker, but if I drag the image slowly it's shaking. I don't get it, I would suspect the `OnMouseMove` and the difference between `FStartPos` and current position, but it keeps constant even if you drag far from the `FStartPos`. [`Here's`](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=198cbd603f4d4d09&resid=198CBD603F4D4D09!152&parid=root) the whole project (compiled in D2009, tested on Windows 7) if you want to take a look.

Comment: @TLama You have attached the mouse events to both the image and the scroll box. Unattach them from the image, and set `Image.Enabled` to False.

Comment: @NGLN, I see it now, thanks! Bounty will arrive in a few hours because it just deserves it ;-)

Comment: @TLama Wow, that's very generous! Thanks!

Comment: This answer is perfect. See related question for Smooth panning a scrollbox "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595166/tscrollbox-mousedown-override". Thanx to NGLN.

Answer (score 0):

In the MouseClickDown event save the X and Y coordinate of mouse cursor in some global variable.

In the MouseMove event calculate the DeltaX = SavedX - CurrentX   and the DeltaY = SavedY - CurrentY   values.
Then scroll your map/image/panel by DeltaX/DeltaY as an absolute value respect your map/image/panel starting position.

In the MouseClickUp event, use the last calculated DeltaX and DeltaY to set the new starting position of your map/image/panel (essentially leaving it where it is) and reset the SavedX and SavedY values.

You'll need to check for maximum scrolling position, for border, for what happen when the mouse cursor go outside the application....