# Custom OnMouseDown that won't brake the click

Tags: delphi, events

Ok I have a function that returns to me a **TMouseEvent** type

I need to execute returned TMouseEvent but I dont know how.

Simple function returning an event:

```
function OMDold(obj: TObject): TMouseEvent
  begin
  ... //some operations on obj 
  result := obj.OnMouseDown; //there is casting necessary, I skip it for simplify
end;
```

Currently the event is set to OMDnew which looks like:

```
procedure TfmAPRBasedForm.TSDragEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if something then dosomething
  else
    begin
      Sender.OnMouseDOwn := OMDold // OMDold in most cases returns null but its ok I just want to clear custom event from the object 
      //line below is a point of my question - the one I used doesnt work
      TButton(Sender).OnMouseDown(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y) //this line throws Access viloation at me
    end;
end;
```

---

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. Geting button default OnMouseDown event and storing it in some record data
2. Changing ONMouseDown event to custom
3. During the custom event procedure there is a condition - if the mouse press was a drag, I execute drag code, if it wasn't I'd proceed with common click
4. To procced with common click I wanted to restore the default event and reeru it so the click could be executed

Thats it

Comment: Why don't you just call `OMDnew`. You can do that you know.

Comment: what is the problem to directly call `OMDnew(sender, button, shift, x,y)` ?

Comment: My description wasn't clear enough. Justmade probably just gave me the right answer. I edited my post however, for further use :)

Comment: Rethought, still not clear to me. Editet my post

Comment: If your OMDold is stored as TMethod then you can use :
TMouseEvent(OMDOld)(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y);

Comment: As you said, Sender.OnMouseDOwn := OMDold usually return nil (not null).  That mean Sender.OnMouseDOwn is also nil. That's why you get AV from invoking it.  You need to add If Assigned(Sender.OnMouseDOwn) then before calling TButton(Sender).OnMouseDown so that it is skipped when Sender.OnMouseDown is empty.

Comment: Yah, the point I don't really wanna skip it. I want to proceed with a click which is ruined because of that custom event. I'm starting to think that I'll have to do TButton(Sender).OnClick(Sender); if assigned returns false

Comment: I had already answered your original question, though it might not actually solved your problem as you had not bring out your problem clearly.  Keep changing the question is not a good way of getting more help.  If you new question is indeed quite different from the original one, you are better asking a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Just call it directly passing the param :

```
procedure TfmAPRBasedForm.TSDragEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if something then dosomething
  else
    begin
      TButton(Sender.OnMouseDOwn) := OMDold // OMDold in most cases returns nil (not null) but its ok I just want to clear custom event from the object 
      //line below is a point of my question - the one I used doesnt work
      If Assigned(TButton(Sender).OnMouseDown) then // Check if there is really an TMouseEvent
        TButton(Sender).OnMouseDown(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y) //Call only when Event exist
    end;
end;
```

You may need to changed the Button, Shift, X, Y though if you are using them in your OMDOld and you need the value other then current value in the dragEvent, like removing ssShift or so.

If your OMDold is stored as TMethod then you can use :

```
TMouseEvent(OMDOld)(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y);
```

Below is a full test example adjusted to show what you want to achieve in similar fashion :

```
Unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure btn2MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure NewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    OMDold : TMouseEvent;
    IsNew : Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OMDold := btn1.OnMouseDown;
  btn1.OnMouseDown := NewMouseDown;
  IsNew := True;
end;

procedure TForm4.NewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsNew then
    ShowMessage('New Method!')
  else if Assigned(OMDold) then
    OMDold(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y);
end;

procedure TForm4.btn1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('Original Method!');
end;

procedure TForm4.btn2MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  IsNew := not IsNew;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Edited my post, I'm not sure if its what I'm looking for

Comment: @JacekKwiecień  It is all the same, just call OMDOld(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y);

Comment: OMDOld can be Nil, so additional check is required.

Comment: it throws access violation at me :( I'm sure OMDold returns proper event - I use OMDold(Sender)(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y);

Comment: tried <CastType>(Sender).OnMouseDown(Sender,Button,Shift,X,Y); but throws exception too

Comment: @Jacek AV mean that the OMDold (or Sender.OnMouseDown is nil as Torbins suggested.  My former version do include a Assigned check.

Comment: added Assigned condition, why does that return false if I did Sender.OnMouseDOwn := OMDold

Comment: @Jacek, that mean your OMDold hold nothing.  For example, you assigned the OMDold by OMDold := button1.OnMouseDown.  However, button1 do not have an OnMouseDown event at that moment, then you assign nothing to OMDold and it will of cause return false to Assign and cause AV when used.

Comment: Thats right, the previous OnMouseDown was empty. However I can set it to empty. It works fine but during the next click. When I call it from inside the event it throws the exception

Comment: @JacekKwiecień I think you need to provide real (maybe simplified) code for us to understand.  You can use my sample code to modify to show your problem.  Also, if you call the event inside the same event without exit control, you will definitely got an exception same with this forum name!

Comment: modified code a little bit + added desciption of what i'm trying to achieve. The code I'm presenting is simplified only a little bit. It basically presents everything I want to do

Answer (score 0):

The sample procedure that stops OnMouseDown from runing the CLick event:

```
procedure TForm1.CustomowyEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
if (DragDetectPlus(TWinControl(Sender))) then ShowMessage('detected drag!')

else
  begin
    TButton(Sender).OnMouseDown := DME;
    TButton(Sender).OnClick(Sender);
  end;
end;
```

`TButton(Sender).OnClick(Sender)`  runs the click so basically if we didn't want to drag it clicks.

Comment: Well this is quite another issue then your question "Using TMouseEvent type to call an event from code" :)

Comment: Just one off topic note if I see the `DragDetectPlus`. I hope this function do more than check if the control is being dragged, because if not it would be better to use the `Dragging` function.

Comment: The one, which has each `TControl` descendant. If the [`Dragging`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Dragging) returns True, the control is being dragged. It was a sidenote to your `DragDetectPlus` function name, so I was wondering what it actually does ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Addressing all question parts separately:

1. **Geting button default `OnMouseDown` event and storing it in some record data**

   Add a private field to your form declaration and assign the old event to it:

   ```
     private
       FOldButtonOnMouseDown: TMouseEvent;
     end;

   ...

     FOldButtonOnMouseDown := Button.OnMouseDown;
   ```
2. **Changing `OnMouseDown` event to custom**

   Assign your custom event handler to the `OnMouseDown` property:

   ```
     private
       procedure NewButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
         Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
     end;

   ...

     Button.OnMouseDown := NewButtonMouseDown;
   ```
3. **During the custom event procedure there is a condition - if the mouse press was a drag, I execute drag code, if it wasn't I'd proceed with common click**

   Test if the original event was assigned and if so, call it:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.NewButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; 
     Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
   begin
     if DragCondition then
       ExecuteDragCode
     else
       if Assigned(FOldButtonOnMouseDown) then
         FOldButtonOnMouseDown(Sender, Button, Shift, X, Y);
   end;
   ```
4. **To procced with common click I wanted to restore the default event and rerun it so the click could be executed**

   Restore the event:

   ```
   Button.OnMouseDown := FOldButtonOnMouseDown;
   ```

Combining this all together is your next challenge. It depends especially on how the drag stuf is implemented, but you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597973/757830) in which I also temporarily exchange the `OnMouseUp` event for undoing all changes.