# How to grab and drag an Image in a ScrollBox?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I'm using C++ Builder XE6 and `TScrollBox`. Inside the ScrollBox component I have a huge picture (TImage). The ScrollBox shows vertical and horizontal scrollbars but I would like to be able to "grab and drag" the image with left mouse button in order to move to different areas of the image. When I say "grab and drag" I mean to have the same effect as moving the horizontal and vertical scrollbars of the `TScrollBox` component. How do I do that?

Comment: Change the mouse cursor to drag when the button is pressed and set a flag which is cleared when the button is released. Track mouse movement as long as the flag exists. Scroll accordingly.

Comment: By "TScrollBar", do you really mean "TScrollBox"? You can't put child controls in a `TScrollBar`.

Comment: [This is your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503002/757830).